# How to use calibration result of easy_handeye

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have calibrated my camera using  [easy_handeye](https://github.com/IFL-CAMP/easy_handeye) and using [publish.launch](https://github.com/IFL-CAMP/easy_handeye/blob/master/easy_handeye/launch/publish.launch)  to launch the calibration result. However, I would like to know how I can use this calibration result for my code, where I want to pick and place objects using a robotic arm.

Here is the list of publisher that is publishing the result of hand-eye calibration and subscriber that are subscribing the result.

```
$ rostopic info /tf_static 
Type: tf2_msgs/TFMessage

Publishers: 
 * /xarm_realsense_handeyecalibration_eye_on_hand/handeye_publisher_akumar_ThinkPad_P17_Gen_2i_114376_5000672119570238070 (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:40065/)
 * /robot_state_publisher (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:34185/)
 * /camera/realsense2_camera_manager (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:39165/)
 * /xarm_realsense_handeyecalibration_eye_on_hand/handeye_publisher_akumar_ThinkPad_P17_Gen_2i_114681_6997610453558885147 (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:38563/)

Subscribers: 
 * /move_group (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:44351/)
 * /xarm_move_group_planner (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:38529/)
 * /rviz_akumar_ThinkPad_P17_Gen_2i_114681_6050782860401126934 (http://akumar-ThinkPad-P17-Gen-2i:36855/)
```

After seeing the above output, I feel that `xarm_move_group_planner` or `move_group` uses the calibration result internally. Therefore, I do not need additional subscribers and publishers to transform the data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408075/how-to-use-calibration-result-of-easy_handeye/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-18**:\

> How can I use this calibration result for my code, where I want to pick and place objects using a robotic arm?

I strongly recommend going through [MoveIt Tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/index.html). Once you get the idea, you may ask specific question.

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-10-19**:
I would like to use the calibrated result (camera on base) in moveIt python api, how can I use that ? Please let me know if you want me to be more detailed. I followed few tutorial and let me be more clear, I have calibrated eye on base result and got the yaml file, I would like to know do I have to write any code or just need to publish the data(https://github.com/IFL-CAMP/easy_handeye/blob/master/easy_handeye/launch/publish.launch) and the moveit api would itself use the data to do the required transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue ha been resolved using `tf.TransformListener()` and publishing the transformed data into base frame.
Example code:

```
        (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/link_base', '/marker_1', rospy.Time(0))
        val = np.array([trans[0],trans[1],trans[2],rot[0],rot[1],rot[2],rot[3]],dtype=np.float64)
        marker_wrt_base.publish(val)
```

---

Originally posted by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) with karma: 61 on 2022-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0